# Problems with Angular ui router and Express

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack

I think I made some obvious mistake with routing. I refered tons of stackoverflow threads. But Nothing helps. Been Stuck into this for a day. Please help. Thanks in advance.

**File Structure**

```
   myApp
   --- client
       --- css
       --- js
       --- lib
       --- views
           -- index.html, movies.html, etc.,
   --- node_modules
   --- server
   --- server.js
```

**app.js**

```
   var movieApp=angular.module('movieApp',['ui.router']);

    movieApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){


        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/movies');
        $stateProvider
            .state('movies', {
                url:"/movies",
                templateUrl:"movies.html"
            })
            .state('viewMovie', {
                url:"/movies/:id/view",
                templateUrl:"view-movie.html"
            })
            .state('editMovie', {
                url:"/movies/:id/edit",
                templateUrl:"edit-movie.html"
            })
            .state('newMovie', {
                url:"/movies/new",
                templateUrl:"new-movie.html"
            })
    });
```

**server.js**

```
   var express = require('express'),
        app     =  express(),
     router  = express.Router();

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
    app.use(router);

    router.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
    });

    app.listen(3000);
```

Getting Warning:
Trying to load angular more than once.

Here is my try out:

================================================

**Try Out 1:**

In **app.js**

I set html5mode true

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And added absolute path to my templateUrls

In **index.html**

I set base href

```
<base href="/">
```

In **server.js**

```
   router.get('/*', function(req, res) {
       res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/views/index.html');
   });
```

Still same problem :(

=================================================

Here is my index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Movie APP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"/>
        <base href="/">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/angular/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/services.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="movieApp">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="movies">myMovies.com</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a ui-sref="movies">Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

     <div class="container">
         <div ui-view=""></div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your code, the issue may be within your base file / layout file , i.e, index.html. Please check, perhaps you have included angular js more than once in your file. Check..

And let me know if still issue exist.

Comment: I updated my index.html for your reference. I am sure that i include angular only once.